# Add indicator to BottomNavigationBar in flutter

Tags: flutter

any way to add indicator to BottomNavigatorBarItem like this image?
[image: fl]

Comment: you should consider building your own BottomNavigationBar UI using various Widgets. I will try to give a complete code after I am done with my Coffee xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://pub.dev/packages/titled_navigation_bar) package should be able to help you achieve it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was able to add the indicator by providing activeIcon with BoxDecoration, how ever there is no sliding effect for it.
The library above provides sliding effect but can only either icon or text. I clone and change the `_buildItemWidget` function to make it always show both. It works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TabBar` instead of a `BottomNavigationBar` using a custom decoration:

```dart
class TopIndicator extends Decoration {
  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) {
    return _TopIndicatorBox();
  }
}

class _TopIndicatorBox extends BoxPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
    Paint _paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.lightblue
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..isAntiAlias = true;

    canvas.drawLine(offset, Offset(cfg.size!.width + offset.dx, 0), _paint);
  }
}
```

Then pass the decoration to the TapBar using `TapBar(indicator: TopIndicator ...)`.

[image: tabbar]

To use the TabBar as the `Scaffold.bottomNavigationBar`, you will most likely want to wrap it in a `Material` to apply a background color:

```dart
Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: Material(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: TabBar(
      indicator: TopIndicator(),
      tabs: const <Widget>[
        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined), text: 'Reward'),
        ...
      ],
    ),
  ),
  ...
)
```

Thanks [Ara Kurghinyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67530959/1584915) for the original idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and all the packages I found seem to require raw IconData, which makes it impossible to use widget functionality like number badges (e.g. the number of unread chat messages).

I came up with my own little solution; first, I made a widget to display the actual indicators:

```
class TabIndicators extends StatelessWidget {
  final int _numTabs;
  final int _activeIdx;
  final Color _activeColor;
  final Color _inactiveColor;
  final double _padding;
  final double _height;

  const TabIndicators({ 
    required int numTabs, 
    required int activeIdx, 
    required Color activeColor, 
    required double padding,
    required double height,
    Color inactiveColor = const Color(0x00FFFFFF),
    Key? key }) : 
    _numTabs = numTabs, 
    _activeIdx = activeIdx,
    _activeColor = activeColor, 
    _inactiveColor = inactiveColor,
    _padding = padding,
    _height = height,
    super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final elements = <Widget>[];

    for(var i = 0; i < _numTabs; ++i) {
      elements.add(
        Expanded(child: 
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: _padding),
            child: Container(color: i == _activeIdx ? _activeColor : _inactiveColor),
          )
        )
      );
    }

    return 
      SizedBox(
        height: _height,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: elements,
    ),
      );
  }
}
```

This can be prepended to the actual BottomNavigationBar like this:

```
bottomNavigationBuilder: (context, tabsRouter) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        TabIndicators(
          activeIdx: tabsRouter.activeIndex,
          activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          numTabs: 4,
          padding: 25,
          height: 4,
        ),
        BottomNavigationBar(...
```

This works perfectly well for me, but to make it look decent, you'd have to set the BottomNavigationBar's elevation to zero, otherwise there's still a faint horizontal line between the indicators and the icons.