# How to add top lines in navbar - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, design-patterns, mobile

I am relatively new to flutter and I was wondering how to make this design possible. I assume I have to use dividers etc but I haven't been able to figure out how to make it works. Here is the design:

[image]

I would really appreciate any suggestions or ideas. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This has already been asked here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368310/add-indicator-to-bottomnavigationbar-in-flutter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement it with `TabBar` by creating a custom indicator

TabBar(
indicator: CustomIndicator(),
...
)

```
class CustomIndicator extends Decoration {
  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([void Function() onChanged]) {
    return _TopIndicatorBox();
  }
}

class _TopIndicatorBox extends BoxPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
    Paint _paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.yellow
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..isAntiAlias = true;

    canvas.drawLine(offset, Offset(cfg.size.width + offset.dx, 0), _paint);
  }
}
```